# Determine if the the transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to determine whether the transformation is linear. My guesswork/rough work shows that the transformation is linear, but I don't think the process is correct. I apologize for my atrocious handwriting, and appreciate any help.

[My guess work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HflBA.jpg)

Comment: The zero transformation/matrix is linear since it sends everything to zero. In general, however, you will want to check the two conditions required for linearity.

Comment: Hi twosigma, I understand that 0 transformation are linear since it satisfies addition and scalar multiplication properties. I was just trying to show that A induces T, which I am not sure I showed correctly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, the 0 matrix corresponds to the zero transformation. If the matrix has a zero, it cannot correspond to the zero transformation (why?). In general, your steps for showing that $A$ induces $T$ is correct (why?).